# WPF Treeview: How to display rounded border around the selected item?

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I am trying to set the rounded border around the selected item of the treeview (like the one in the windows explorer on Vista). The problem is that the trigger in the following code doesn't seem to be working. It looks like the IsSelected property is always false.

```
 <TreeView x:Name="m_treeView" BorderThickness="0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <Brush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}">Transparent</Brush>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DirectoryPresentationBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TreeViewItem>
                        <TreeViewItem.Header>
                            <Border  Name="SelectedBorder"  CornerRadius="3" Background="#EFF8FD" BorderBrush="#99DEFD"
                                     BorderThickness="1" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <local:TreeViewExpandBehavior AssociatedTreeView="{Binding ElementName=m_treeView}"/>
                                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <Image x:Name="img" Width="24" Height="16" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding SmallIcon}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </TreeViewItem.Header>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="SelectedBorder"  Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="SelectedBorder"  Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="SelectedBorder"  Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="SelectedBorder"  Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remove trigger `IsSelected=False`. It will automatically revert all changes when `IsSelected` will become not `True`.

Second, move triggers to `TreeView.Resources`:

```
            <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                .....
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
```

Third, remove `TreeViewItem` tag. Use `Border` directly inside of `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. That's because everything you put inside `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is already instantiated inside of some `TreeViewItem`.

Fourth, bind border's background and border brush to treeviewitem's ones

```
Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"
BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"
```

Comment: I don't know how to avoid this `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` resource setting - it makes setting highlighted color to a system one very hard. But as long as you use only predefined colors, it's fine.